# How to write a test case for dispatch in jest for React Native?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, automated-tests

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    branch.subscribe(({ params }) => {
      if (
        params &&
        params['+clicked_branch_link'] &&
        params['+match_guaranteed']
      ) {
        dispatch(updateBranchioDetails(params));
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I have used the dispatch function and tried to write a test case for the above code.

```
it('calls dispatch when branch.subscribe is called with valid params', () => {
    const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
    jest.spyOn(mockDispatch, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(dispatchMock);

    const mockParams = {
      '+clicked_branch_link': true,
      '+match_guaranteed': true,
    };

    branch.subscribe({ params: mockParams });

    expect(mockDispatch.useDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(updateBranchioDetails(mockParams));
  });
```

The above is the test suite, When I try to run the test coverage, I am facing the below issue.

> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
>
> Expected: \[Function anonymous\]
>
> Number of calls: 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to test block **dispatch(updateBranchioDetails(params))**

my idea is mocking updateBranchioDetails first, and on the expect part, just expect dispatch should be call with value that you set on mocking updateBranchioDetails

ex.

```
// mocking external deps
jest.mock('./some_place', () => ({
   updateBranchioDetails: jest.fn()
}))

it('calls dispatch when branch.subscribe is called with valid params', () => {
    // like when below function is called, it's will return parameter
    updateBranchioDetails.mockImplementation((params) => params)
    const dispatchMock = jest.fn();
    jest.spyOn(mockDispatch, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(dispatchMock);

    const mockParams = {
      '+clicked_branch_link': true,
      '+match_guaranteed': true,
    };

    branch.subscribe({ params: mockParams });

    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockParams)
```

Comment: When I try to use the solution you provided, I get this error.

Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '(data: {}) => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<void>'.

Could you provide me with more detail?